# Is there a reason a column in a MySQL table would have a unique and normal index on it?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

So this is a question I've been asking the pyroCMS guys because while rummaging through there source I noticed the news_categories table for the news module has 2 indexes on the "slug" column .

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. If there's a unique index on a column, there's no use for a separate "normal" index. Unless one of those indexes is actually a multi-column index.

Comment: the SQL for the creation of the table is here. https://gist.github.com/671584

Comment: I'm betting the reason is "incompetence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in creating a non-unique index and it will only degrade write performance on the table (since two identical indexes will need to be maintained).

It is interesting that `Oracle` behaves more consistently in such situations.

If you instruct `Oracle` to create a plain index on a column already indexed with `UNIQUE` index (or vice versa), it will throw an error.

However, if you create a plain index and then create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` (using `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`), it will create the constraint and will use the existing plain index to enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make sense to have 2 indexes on the same column.